# ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to edit a user, I get the error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: user

with the params.require line highlighted:

```
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role, :university_id, :password, :password_confirmation)

  end
```

I've looked at similar questions for solutions but can't seem to get it to work. Any help for a rookie would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"PfLU2rMWnEMj4Nez+tNhsZz9v9z2jGmCTUXOOElmv9NMK6j8LTzvSuJGL9iH/cx02vb7Po3tSQIKmMXNPVhULg==",
 "staff"=>{"name"=>"fake alogo", "email"=>"fake@alogo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Save changes",
 "id"=>"103"}
```

Here is the form I'm using to edit users:

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Here is the users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

   def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @referral_requests = @user.referral_requests.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end

    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role, :university_id, :password, :password_confirmation)

  end

    # Before filters


    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :role
  enum role: { Staff: 0, Clinician: 1, Admin: 2 }
  belongs_to :university
  has_many :referral_requests

  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :role, presence: true


  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end


  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

 # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

   # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

 def feed
    ReferralRequest.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end


 private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end


end


class Staff < User
  validates :university_id, presence: true
end

class Clinician < User
  has_many :lists
  has_many :universities, through: :lists
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the examples, that you've provided, Request params contain `staff`:

```
"staff"=>{"name"=>"fake alogo", ...
```

but do not contain `user` as defined strong params require to:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role, :university_id, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

That's because `@user` in `form_for` method is an instance of `Staff` class. And `form_for` by default names the params as `staff`.

Luckily, there's `as` option for `form_for` for configuring this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, as: :user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

It should send the params as `"user" => {"name" => ...}`